# как выровнять flex по центру?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята,как выровнять flex по центру?
стоит display: flex;  justify-content: space-between; align-content: center;

Comment: justify-content: center;

Comment: Вот тебе удочка - http://flexboxfroggy.com/  Рыбу лови сам!)

Comment: align-content не работает

Comment: может дело в бутстрапе?кстати,как в бустрапе поставить элемент по центру?

Comment: только паддинги и марджины?

Answer (score 1):

Выражайтесь точнее, по центру по горизонтали или по вертикали?

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 8px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.wrapper:nth-child(2) {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button>Lorem</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button>Lorem</button>
  </div>
</div>
```